# Mapping in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing DB schema like this (cant change it ..) . I need to do a EF mapping

`Student` table:

```
ID    Name     CourseID
------------------------
 1    Name1     100023
 2    Name2     100023
 3    Name3     100024  
 4    Name4     NULL
```

`Course` table:

```
ID   CourseID   CourseName
--------------------------
 1   100023      Course1  
 2   100022      Course2  
 3   100024      Course3  
 4   100023      Course1
```

`ID` is the primary key in both the tables. `CourseID` is the column for the relationships.

There is no explicit relationship in the database (SQL Server) also.

When I try to do a mapping in EF by specifying `CourseID` as the key required to do the mapping it throws up an error telling it is not defined as the key property. I cannot add it as the Key property as it is a null-able field.

Is there any way I could do this mapping?

Comment: Looks like you might be able to do it with EF Core: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Comment: @Steve This relationship doesn't seems to be intuitive .seems like a many to many relationship with only two tables.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can in your mapping, but you could set it up as a private method to do it within your Repository/Data Access logic.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't look right at all assuming a student can have multiple courses.

Comment: You cannot do this mapping in EF, since EF allows only FK's to be mapped. since CourseId is no FK (because CourseId is no Key), EF has no way to determine which entry is supposed to be linked because it has no key information. However, you could join in LINQ to do this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty rough schema to work with. However, you might be able to use a composite key for the `courses` table. I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.

```
public class Course
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int? CourseID { get; set; }

    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? CourseID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```